# Add extent to ArcGIS Webapp URL

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have published an ArcGIS Online Web App. It is working as intended. I am now looking at incorporating additional functionality such as querying features in the map via URL.

I can get this to work using the:

?query=... addition to the URL.
Ie:

```
https://[my web app]?id=xxxx?query=xxx
```

When I try add an extent onto the URL I get an error.  The page loads with an unhappy emoji and instructions the code has been turned to lowercase.

Here is the url as an example:

```
https://[my AGOL address]/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=xxxx?extent=MinX,MinY,MaxX,MaxY,WKID
```

The error on the webpage is:

[image]

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
```

If I remove the “Id=xxx” and use the ArcGIS online base URL and same extent, it loads as intended. Just not in my web app.

Is there a way to control the extent of my web app using the URL?

Comment: URL parameters are well documented. Please see https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/latest/manage-apps/app-url-parameters.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_7D207DF919C049D68B7F9E1423962B4E

Comment: Thank you. That link is what I have used to set up the extent url. The example given does not include the “?id=“ parameter. Which is my question, can you used the extent parameter with a published web app?

Comment: I answered the question you asked. Perhaps a better way to word your actual question is: "How do I use multiple URL parameters in one URL?". To which the answer to that question is found on the first paragraph of the page I provided.

"To include more than one parameter, use an ampersand (&) to separate the parameters."

Answer (score 0):

I noticed an example had used "&" instead of "?".

I changed the url to read:

```
https://[my AGOL address]/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=xxxx&extent=MinX,MinY,MaxX,MaxY,WKID
```

The url now works as intended.